# How to get an array of dates (specifically formatted) from today to a certain point in the past?

Tags: php, arrays, date, datetime

I would like to get an array containing strings like this: 2013-03, 2013-02, 2013-01, 2012-12, 2012-11... etc.

How would I go about it? I tried working with a loop and DateInterval class, but surprisingly 30.March -1month gives us 2.March, so that's not very useful.

```
$date = new DateTime();
$date->sub(DateInterval::createFromDateString('1 month'));
```

Thanks!

Comment: Take a look at http://php.net/dateperiod

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Curiously, PHP returns the previous month of a date using the "next month" keyword :S

You can do the following:

```
<?php
$date = new DateTime();
// Subtract one month at a time
// until we reach 2009.
while ($date->format('Y') > 2009) {
    $date->sub(DateInterval::createFromDateString('next month'));
    var_dump($date->format('Y-m')); // Will print 2013-03 2013-02 [...]
};
?>
```